# Add names with comma in selectize box

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I need my users to be able to add names in a selectize dropdown.

This works fine unless the user puts a comma in the string input. The comma key seems to trigger the "createItem" method, therefore preventing proper inputting.

Some investigation in the selectize source code led me to this line:

```
return this.settings.create && b === this.settings.delimiter ? (this.createItem(),
        a.preventDefault(),
        !1) : void 0
```

where `b` is the key input `this.settings.delimiter` is a comma. So it looks like selectize is fundamentally averse to commas in input.

Anyway to overcome that ?

Answer (score 5):

Found it ! `this.settings.delimiter` is a parameter one can settle when creating the selectize input. Through shiny (my case) one sets the parameter by adding `options(delimiter = ';')` that will use a semicolon instead of a comma.